# How can I generate a TimeStamp string for servers in a different time zone

Tags: string, powershell, datetime

I have a list of Reboot time stamps for multiple servers in a CSV file.  I'm looking for a method to convert the timestamp of a remote server, for example in the Eastern Time Zone, into Pacific Time.

In my testing, I set a future date `[datetime]$a="05-28-16 18:00"`

Then convert that to Dmtf format, how would I perform this for a remote server?  Because [this article](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2012/04/20/parsing-remote-machine-local-date-and-time-with-wmi/) points out the conversion is performed locally not remotely.

```
$b=[System.Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDmtfDateTime($a)
```

And finally look up a remote server's `ConvertToDateTime` Script Method.  But I think the problem is it's being converted and displayed in my local time.

```
(gwmi -comp EasternServer101 win32_timezone).ConvertToDateTime($b)
Returns:
Saturday, May 28, 2016 6:00:00 PM
```

Comment: Edited question, hopefully this is more specific

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get something working.

To avoid converting times to the local time, I explicitly target Pacific Standard Time offset. This is a fairly manual way to do it, but I'm unsure of any built in cmdlets that might help out here.

Basically, find the timezone offset of the remote machine and remove it from the time. Then find the timezone offset of Pacific Time and add it to time. Then regardless of what timezone you and the target machine are in, the result should be Pacific Time (not sure if PST has daylight time?).

```
#using your test value for a reboot time...
[DateTime]$a = "05-28-16 18:00"

$RemoteBias = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_TimeZone -ComputerName EasternServer101 ).Bias
$PTBias = [System.TimeZoneInfo]::FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time").BaseUtcOffset.TotalMinutes

$a.AddMinutes(-$RemoteBias).AddMinutes($PTBias)
```

Comment: This is helpful however we've got one problem, Australia.  Their offset is +10 hours from UTC.  Before posting this question I was looking into possibly getting the remote computer's Time Zone Caption, using regex to capture the UTC offset and using that to get my conversion.

Comment: I'm unsure how Australia's timezone is links in here. Which timezone do you want to convert to?